# Is it more performant to use CSS Fill with SVGs or separate SVGs?

Tags: html, css, icons, css-sprites

We currently have a Sprite image that has a bunch SVGs loaded in one. There are two strategies we are thinking to implement, but are struggling to see find which one would be more performant front end wise.

**Options:**

1. Load all SVGs (have a Fill attribute populated in individual files) with all color variations into one sprite image, serve that up on the website, and then use CSS classes to get the one we need.
2. Load all SVGs (no fill attribute populated in individual files) into one sprite image (no color variations), serve up sprite image on the website, and then use CSS classes to get the SVG we need, but also add a CSS `fill` property of `black`, `white`, `blue`, or others as needed.

Examples for each option (1:1)

1. If i wanted the black search icon, i could have a CSS class name of `search--black`, but i wanted a white search icon I could do `search--white`
2. If i wanted the search icon in black, i could use CSS class of `search` + `color--white`

```css
// Option 1.
    .icons {
      background-image: url('/path/to/sprite/');
    }

    .search--black {
      width: 10px;
      height: 20px;
      background-position: 10% 10%;
    }

    .search--white {
      width: 10px;
      height: 20px;
      background-position: 20% 20%;
    }


    // Option 2.

    .icons {
      background-image: url('/path/to/sprite/');
    }

    .search {
      width: 15px;
      height: 20px;
      background-position: 5% 5%;
    }
    .color--white {
      fill: white;
    }
```

```html
<!-- option 1 -->
<span class="icons search--black">Insert black search icon </span>
<span class="icons search--white">Insert white search icon </span>

<!-- option 2 -->
<span class="icons search color--white">Insert white search icon </span>
```

Things that i have considered:

1. With option 1, there is a larger sprite image and less CSS classes needed in `html`
2. with option 2, there is a smaller sprite image, but more CSS as we need additional ones for color

What is more performant and optimal for websites?

Comment: Should not make any 'performance' difference. Since the examples are there, why not test it (on the target browsers/devices)?

Comment: @user2864740 with larger CSS files, it does take longer to load for `option 2` since CSS is render-blocking, but `option 1` has not proven to be that much better since it needs to load a larger sprite image.

Comment: 1) "render blocking" is only relevant for 'some relevant amount of time' (blocking for 0ms = 0ms wasted) and 2) caching, caching, caching.. plus even slow internet connections these days are quite fast.. and given it's an SVG it's probably a relatively small file anyway..